# If $X$ and $Y$ are independent Uniform(-1,1), what is the pdf of $\cos(X) \cos(Y)$?

Tags: probability, distributions, random-variable, uniform-distribution

I have two random variables $X$ and $Y$ which are independent and Uniformly distributed in the interval $\left[-\pi, \pi\right]$.

What will be the pdf of $\cos\left(X\right)\cos\left(Y\right)$?

Comment: $\cos(X)$ has distribution something like $f(y)=\frac{1}{\pi\sqrt{1-y^2}}$ (a beta(1/2,1/2) distribution that's shifted on $[-\pi,\pi]$). So the answer is whatever the product of the two is, which is probably not pretty.

Comment: Are x and y independent?

Comment: 1. Is this for some class? 2. It's not sufficient to specify the marginal distribution -- you need the *joint* distribution, You have left some some information (e.g. independence, as Matthew suggests would be sufficient)

Comment: I very much doubt it is for a class, as obtaining a closed form does not seem obvious (if it is possible). I have made some edits and nominated for re-opening. Also, the pdf of $\cos(X)$ will be ArcSine on (-1,1)

Comment: I agree this is probably a homework question and should be closed given that there's no effort from the OP, but "As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking" is just not true.

Answer (score 3):

This might look like an easy problem, but it is more tricky than it looks.

If $X \sim \text{Uniform}(-1,1)$, then $\cos(X) \sim \text{ArcSine}(-1,1)$ with pdf $f(x)$:

[image]

Then, the pdf of the product of two such independent variables should be attainable via the *mathStatica* function:

> TransformProduct[ {f, f} ]

The 'not so good' news is that this returns an unevaluated integral. The good news is that, by playing around with it a little, one can in fact evaluate the required integral, and derive that the pdf of $V = \cos(X) \cos(Y)$ is:

$$f(v) = \frac{2}{\pi^2}  \frac{ K\left(1-\frac{1}{v^2}\right)}{\left| v\right| } \quad  \quad \text{for } \quad -1 <v<1$$

where $K(.)$ denotes the complete elliptic integral of the first kind (see, for instance: [Elliptic Integral of the First Kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegraloftheFirstKind.html) )

Here is a plot of the solution pdf $f(v)$:

[image]

**Monte Carlo check**

A quick Monte Carlo check confirms that the above theoretical result appears fine ...

- The squiggly blue line is the Monte Carlo approximation of the pdf
- The red dashed line is the exact theoretical solution obtained above

[image]